# Prevent chrome from caching header redirects

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser-cache

I have several views where if the user is not logged in or in other states (cart not empty in checkout view), i redirect him to other places, I have written a method for that, but Google Chrome cache my redirects.

Example: If a user tried to get to the checkout and was redirected because his cart is empty, next time, even if his cart is full, he will get redirected again. Its being solved only after manually going to Chrome's settings and clearing cache and browsing history.

My method:

```
    public static function redirect($url, $statusCode = 302, $cacheHeader = true)
{
    if( $cacheHeader === false ) {
        header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
    }

    header('Location: ' . $url, true, $statusCode);
    exit();
}
```

Calling the method:

```
EkerbaseUtilities::redirect(Ekerbase::getRoot() . '#showcart', 307, false);
```

I've tried with 307, 303 and other statuses, all had the same result. You can also see that Iv'e tried to set a no-cache header, that also did nothing.

Something else i tried is to set ?unique()=1 in the url, for a parameter that always changes, but still got the same result.

Please note that JS redirects are out of the question as UX is key for that site.

Any clue?
Thanks,

Comment: _“Something else i tried is to set ?unique()=1 in the url, for a parameter that always changes, but still got the same result.”_ – It is rather impossible to get a cached redirect for a URL that the browser has not even requested before … On which URL did you try this - the original one the user is send to, before the redirect?

Comment: _“If a user tried to get to the checkout and was redirected because his cart is empty”_ - why do that in the first place? Let them go to the checkout page, and present them with a message telling them that there is nothing to check out, because their cart is empty. Offer additional links like “continue shopping” if you want to guide them further as to what they should/could do now …

Answer (score 2):

Issue was with my .htaccess, I just had to set:

```
Header set Cache-Control max-age=0
```

Fixed the issue completely.

Comment: Fixed completely! Thank you!